# Iterator для многомерного массива

Tags: java, массивы, итераторы

Как реализовать интерфейс `Iterator` для многомерного массива?

Ввод:

```java
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}};
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Предполагаю, что сделать 2 итератора по столбцу и строке.

```java
public class MatrixIterator implements Iterator {
    private int[][] values;
    private int rowIndex = 0;
    private int colIndex = 0;
    private Iterator<Integer> rowIterator;
    private Iterator<Integer> colIterator;

    public MatrixIterator(int[][] values) {
        this.values = values;
        rowIterator = new Iterator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return values.length > rowIndex;
            }
            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                return values[rowIndex++][colIndex];
            }
        };
        colIterator = new Iterator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return values[rowIndex].length > colIndex;
            }
            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                return values[rowIndex][colIndex++];
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (rowIterator.hasNext() && colIterator.hasNext()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        if (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            if (colIterator.hasNext()) {
                return values[rowIndex][colIndex++];
            } else {
                colIndex = 0;
                return values[rowIndex++][colIndex];
            }
        } else return null;
    }
}
```

Тогда как правильно реализовать методы основного класса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для последовательного обхода элементов можно сделать так:

```
public class  MatrixIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
    private int size;          //всего элементов в матрице 
    private int position = 0;  //номер текущего элемента для "выдачи"
    private int row = 0;       //строка текущего элемента
    private int col = 0;       //столбец текущего элемента
    private T[][] matrix;

    public MatrixIterator(T[][] matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
        this.size = countElements(matrix);
    }

    private int countElements(T[][] matrix) {  //считаем количество элементов в матрице
        int count = 0;
        for (T[] row : matrix) {
            count += row.length;
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return position < size;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (position >= size) { //если перебрали все элементы, то бросить исключение
           throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } 
        T element = matrix[row][col];  //запоминаем текущий элемент
        //переходим к следующему элементу
        position++;
        col++;
        while (row < matrix.length && col >= matrix[row].length) { //для того, чтоб пропустить возможные "пустые" строки
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }
        return element;
    }
}
```

В данном случае итератор параметризирован, так что не имеет значения с матрицей какого типа работать. В `row` и `col` сохраняется позиция текущего элемента, который необходимо вернуть. Цикл `while` для того, чтоб пропустить возможные пустые строки (например, `{{1, 2, 3}, {}, {4, 5}, {6}}`). Использовать итератор можно следующим образом

```
Integer[][] matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {4, 5}, {6}};
Iterator<Integer> iterator = new MatrixIterator<>(matrix);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Другой вариант:

```
public class IteratorFor2DArray implements Iterator {

    private int[][] data;
    private int i, j;

    public IteratorFor2DArray(int[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        int element = data[i][j];
        j++;
        while (i < data.length && j >= data[i].length) {
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (i < data.length && j < data[i].length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать внутри `hasNext()` итерироваться по массиву с помощью `forEach` и выдавать нужный объект.

```java
private class ElementsIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    T[][] value;

    private int cursor = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        //Равен нулю каждый раз при входе в метод.
        int nextCursor = 0;

        for (T x[] : value) {
            for (T y : x) {
                //сброшенный nextCursor поднимается
                //до уровня текущей позиции cursor
                //и отдает нужный элемент.
                if (nextCursor++ == cursor) {
                    cursor++;
                    return y;
                }
            }
        }
        //Если перед вызовом next()
        //проверять есть ли элементы,
        //то сюда у нас программа не дойдет.
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Наподобие цикла в цикле или итератора в итераторе, то же самое можно сделать на `Stream`:

```java
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}};

// обходим двумерный массив и умножаем каждый элемент на 10
IntStream.range(0, arr.length).forEach(i ->
        IntStream.range(0, arr[i].length).forEach(j -> {
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] * 10;
        }));

// выводим двумерный массив
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [10, 20, 30]
// [40, 50]
```

Или можно объединить вложенные массивы в один `Stream` и обойти его:

```java
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}};

// обходим двумерный массив
// и умножаем каждый элемент на 10,
// получаем одномерный массив
int[] arr1 = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .map(i -> i * 10)
        .toArray();

// выводим одномерный массив
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
// [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```